# How to resize pickerwheel on corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I already made a pickerwheel on a `320x480` size device but now I'm changing my config to `640x960`.

My pickerwheel is too small and I need to enlarge it?

Is there a possible way to resize it?

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience:

```
 "widget.newPickerWheel  Does not support scaling"
```

So you can't directly assign `width` or `height` properties or `scale` the picker.
But you can create the picker and set the dimensions by Customising the picker with a `Custom Image Sheet`. You can try the `Custom Image Sheet` example from the API below to implement your need:

[Corona Docs API: widget.newPickerWheel()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newPickerWheel.html#TOC)

Keep Coding................. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this topic is a bit old but actually you can adjust the width in `newPickerWheel({ width = value })`.

It must have been added in the meantime. You have to download and install the (latest) [daily build](https://developer.coronalabs.com/downloads/daily-builds/).

You can find the corresponding documentation [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/widget/newPickerWheel.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need pickerWheels, I would recommend keeping your content area at 320x480.  Because of the chrome that goes with it, the images are fixed size, which is why you cannot specify a width and height.

Comment: Yah, that is one of my mistake. I should have use 640x960 on games but when developing on utility apps that needs widget, 320x480 is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

The picker wheel doesnot support scaling.

PickerWheels do not support scaling nor changing the width/height via .width or .height.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newPickerWheel.html

Answer (score 0):

With version build 2016.2992 of Corona SDK you get

> Widget picker wheels are now resizable so that you can incorporate
>   them into your UI with much greater flexibility. Keep an eye out for
>   an upcoming announcement which summarizes this addition and other new
>   features.

Full information you can find on [Corona Blog](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2016/11/16/new-public-build-2016-2992-now-available/).